# Не получается вызвать статический метод в другом классе

Tags: java, static

Есть публичный класс GoogleAnalyticsApi в пакете api_connection
В этом классе есть публичный статический метод getResultsFromGA.

Есть контроллер в папке controllers GaUniversalController
Почему у меня не получается вызвать метод GoogleAnalyticsApi. getResultsFromGA в контроллере GaUniversalController?

Вот визуализация.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кот корректная работа main класса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странно, автокомплит вообще работает на GoogleAnalyticsApi? Может идея тупит

Comment: Да, всё работает. Если я перенесу в main вызов метода - он корреконо работает

Comment: А всё, вижу, у вас вызов метода вне метода класса

Comment: Точно, спасибо!!!!!